# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () what does error mean?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an authentication App by using Firestore and I could sign in and sign up the user, but after sometime when I opened my console this error occur:[image: THIS IS THE ERROR I SEE IN CONSOLE LOG WHEN I OPENED CONSOLE LOG AGAIN]

What caused this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Most often the 400 status response means you have not provided the request parameters that the request expects. Would be much more helpful if we code see the code you are using to call the firebase server as well as what you are sending to them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I am also facing the same error

Comment: Front End / Back End issues like this are always very frustrating. If you can write an integration test to try to deSerialize the payload (harvest the JSON payload) of the FE using the type of the BE controller. You will very very quickly identify what the problem is. Do this for each parameter of the BE endpoint.

Comment: If there is already a solution, I'm also very interested, because I've the same error here

Answer (score 0):

Check this website out for all of the codes...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
400 specifically means that the server blocked the request because of the client.